# C exec, awk, not working

Tags: c, file, unix, awk, exec

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAXLINE 512
main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    int k;
    for (k=0; k<=argc; k++) {
        if (k%2==0) {
            if (fork()==0){

    FILE *fi;
    FILE *fo;
    int i;
    fi=fopen(argv[k], "r");
    fo=fopen("temp.txt","w");
    if (!fi)
        return;
    char linie[MAXLINE],*p;
    for ( ; ; ) {
        p = fgets(linie, MAXLINE, fi);
        if (p == NULL)
            break;
        linie[MAXLINE-1] = '\0';
        int k=-1;
        for (i = 0; i <MAXLINE; i++) {
            if (linie[i]=='\n') k=i;
        }
        for (i = k; i >= 0; --i) {
            fprintf(fo,"%c", linie[i]);
        }
    }
    fclose(fi);
    fclose(fo);
                exit(1);}
        }
else
{
    if (fork()==0){
        execl("/usr/bin/awk","awk","-f","ouk.awk",argv[k],NULL);
        exit(1);
    }

}
    }

    };
```

here is the ouk.awk file content

```
{ for (i=NF;i>=1;i--){ if(s){s=s" "$i} else{s=$i }}{print s;s=""}}
```

Basically what i try to do is create a number of argc processes and is the number is even to mirror the text in the file and if not to rearrange the words from every line backwards, the problem I'm facing is

> fprintf(fo,"%c",line[j])

is not working and I also get an error when I try to execute the awk script

> ```
> awk: can't open file >
>  input record number 6, file >
>  source line number 1
> ```

if I run only the awk command in terminal with the same files it works perfectly so it must have something to do with the execl command.

One more thing, I've tried the following command to rename the temp.txt int argv[k]

```
execl("bin/mv","temp.txt",argv[k],NULL)
```

but it crashes.

If anyone could help me or give me a link to a good exec c command tutorial it would be fantastic, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop is going beyond the bounds of the array (which is undefined behaviour):

```
for (k=0; k<=argc; k++) {
    /* ...snip... */
    fi=fopen(argv[k], "r");
```

as arrays have zero based index, running from `0` to `N-1` where `N` is the number of elements in the array. The terminating condition of the `for` must be `k < argc`. Additionally, the first element in `argv` is the name of the program which you will want to exclude:

```
for (k = 1; k < argc; k++)
```

When invoking [`execl()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl) you need to cast the last argument to a `char*`:

```
execl("/usr/bin/awk","awk","-f","ouk.awk",argv[k], (char*)NULL);
```

Comment: @JackRobinson, it might work but from the linked reference page: _The list of arguments must be terminated by a NULL pointer, and, since these are variadic functions, this pointer must be cast (char *) NULL._