# execl command to write on file

Tags: c, unix, exec

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAXLINE 512
main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    int k;

    for (k=0; k<argc; k++) {
        if (k%2==0) {
            if (fork()==0){
                execl("/user/bin/rev","rev",argv[k],">",argv[k],NULL);
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        else
         {
         if (fork()==0){
         execl("/usr/bin/awk","awk","-f","ouk.awk",argv[k],">",argv[k],NULL);
         exit(1);


         }
             wait(0);
    }

}
}
```

awk script

```
{ for (i=NF;i>=1;i--){ if(s){s=s" "$i} else{s=$i }}{print s;s=""}}
```

Could someone please tell why this does not work? What I am trying to do is modify
the file argv[i] using the awk script or the rev command

Thanks

Comment: `why this does not work? ` Please explain

Comment: because it does not modify the file , if i launch the commands separately they work, but like this it doesn't

Comment: Is it not similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16013336/c-exec-awk-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have piping (`>`) work a shell needs to be involved. The OP's code does not call a shell but starts the `awk` process directly.

You might like to replace this line:

```
execl("/usr/bin/awk","awk","-f","ouk.awk",argv[k],">",argv[k],NULL);
```

by those:

```
char cmd[PATHMAX] = "";
sprintf(cmd, "\"/usr/bin/awk -f out.awk %s > %s\"", argv[k], argv[k]);
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", cmd, (char *) NULL);
/* As execl() does not return if successful, getting here indicates an error! */
perror("execl() failed");
```

(This implies that the strings referenced by `argv[k]`do not contain spaces.)

For details please see your shell's man pages. Note that `/bin/sh` commonly is linked to some other shell program like `bash`.